# func locationManager (manager: CLLocationManager, didUpdateLocations locations: [CLLocation]) in swift 2.0

Tags: swift, cllocationmanager, swift2

I have an issue with my code the `didUpdateLocations` function is never called.

I have also add the two keys `NSLocationWhenInUseUsageDescription` and `NSLocationAlwaysUsageDescription`. I have no idea what is going on if any one can help please

```
@IBOutlet weak var mapView: GMSMapView!

let locationManager = CLLocationManager()

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    locationManager.delegate = self
    self.locationManager.requestWhenInUseAuthorization()
    self.locationManager.requestAlwaysAuthorization()


}

override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()

}


func locationManager(manager: CLLocationManager, didChangeAuthorizationStatus status: CLAuthorizationStatus)
{
    if status == .AuthorizedWhenInUse
    {
        locationManager.startUpdatingLocation()
        mapView.myLocationEnabled = true
        mapView.settings.myLocationButton = true
    }
}
func locationManager (manager: CLLocationManager, didUpdateLocations locations: [CLLocation])
{
    if let location = locations.first
    {
        mapView.camera = GMSCameraPosition(target: location.coordinate, zoom: 15, bearing: 0, viewingAngle: 0)
        locationManager.stopUpdatingLocation()
        print(locationManager.location?.coordinate)

    }
}
```

Comment: Does `locationManager.startUpdatingLocation()` get called? Did you include the `CLLocationManagerDelegate` delegate within your class?

Comment: Please check whether location services are enabled in settings. and check CLLocationManager.authorizationStatus()

Comment: ceceXX yes locationManager.startUpdatingLocation is called and yes i had include CLLocationManagerDelegate in my class

Comment: Shailesh Chandavar the location services are enabled on the simulator the status is AuthorizedWhenInUse and it gets to if statement

Comment: also when am trying to print(locationManager.location) it returns nil

Comment: Please follow the instructions  solution1: 1.Open the simulator go to Debug> Location> FreewayDrive 2.Then next time add a custom location                      solution2:  go to Debug> Location>and select city run. It should work

Comment: by that is point in somewhere in london and not my location